# Is there a good synonym for "a group connected to a N-atom"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

I'm writing a publication in which I compare the effect of alkyl, alkene and similar chains of different length connected to a N-atom of a heterocyclic organic compound. Often I have to refer to these chains, *without the N-atom*.

Right now I'm using something like "the ethyl/propyl/etc. group connected to the N-atom", which feels awkward. Is there a better chemical term I could use? Based on my online research, *amine group* or *amine substituent* appears to be the closest, but it includes the nitrogen itself.

Some examples (not from my work):

[image: a few examples]

Is there a term that properly describes the encircled parts?

Comment: Though I asked the question in general, the molecule I'm concerned with has the nitrogen in a ring structure, like my examples. If there's no general name, one applying for this specific case would also suffice.

Comment: o.O Looks like you have a fundamental misunderstanding. Substituents are named for what they are, not what they are connected to.

Comment: @Mithoron I know how it looks like, but (I think) it's not a misunderstanding. I'm working with molecules with different length of CH-groups attached to a the N-atom of a pyrinide ring. I'm comparing certain (density-like) quantities on the ring (including the N) and on the connected group (excluding the N). It's kind of awkward to refer to this "tail" as "the ethyl/propyl/etc. group connected to the N-atom", so I was looking for a general way to refer them at.

Comment: Amyl is an old name for pentyl, so you at least have *a* misunderstanding. Substituents are substituents, in particular alkyl, or aryl groups.

Comment: @Mithoron That was a mental typo on my part. fixed.

Comment: See [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/155812#155812) in *resources learning chemistry*, especially the Blue Book (or chapter 4, P-44 of [Moss' compilation](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/)): first you define the senior chain/cycle/motif of structure; second the substitutents/side chains.  But the name of an "ethyl", "acetyl", or "3-methoxyphenyl" side chain is not determined by what atom of the more senior motif binds to this side chain.

Comment: Where is the problem ? Your first molecule is N-ethylpyrrole; the second is N-acetylpyrrole.

Comment: @Maurice I need a general word to refer to the circled groups, ot the name of the molecules.

Comment: If general, what about "N-substituent", "N-substituent in X"  or "R-N" in a formula?

Comment: @Poutnik wouldn't that still include the N-atom? I arrived to a phrase like "N-bound chain" but it feels a bit clumsy.

Comment: As I assume N may be bound by various ways, I doubt there could be a general name covering N implicitly. Try a general name *without* the substituent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think "N-substituent" is just fine.

A substituent refers to whatever is sticking off something. The prefix "N-" doesn't change that; rather, it qualifies what it is sticking off. So the N-substituent doesn't mean "the nitrogen plus the substituent", but rather "the substituent sticking off the nitrogen".

(As a parallel example: in, say, aromatic rings it is common to refer to a C-2 substituent or an *ortho*-substituent or something. This doesn't include the carbon on the ring, it just refers to whatever's sticking off it.)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the locant *N*- and by biochemical nomenclature for glycolisation, I could see use of the term “*N*-linked moiety”.